# Как долго хранятся сообщения в чате?

Tags: поддержка, чат

https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/

Как долго хранится сама переписка?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Бесконечно при условии что обладающий соответствующими правами не перенесёт и не удалит.

Вот 31 марта 2015 - момент создания основного чата: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/22462/2015/3/31

Comment: спасибо :) а есть какие-нибудь условия, при которых его могут закрыть...ну там например не активен 30 суток или т. п.

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц, там вроде в справке описано, когда чего закрывается. Я точно не помню. Но зарытые чаты можно восстановить. Удалённые - тоже. А вот удалённые сообщения - нельзя.

Comment: Спасибо больше )

Comment: Как это нельзя восстанавливать удалённые сообщения? Может ромб нужен более ромбовидный?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, я про сообщения чата - читать можно, восстанавливать нельзя.

Comment: Можно проголосовать за [фичу](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/270275/339911).

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, проголосовал.